# How do I run zip commands via PHP on Xampp?

Tags: php, xampp, 7zip

I've installed 7zip and I am enjoying it's functionality via my Windows Vista command prompt. However, I'm now using the commands via PHPs exec() function on my Xampp installation, and am not having any issues.

It doesn't matter what 7z syntax I issue, I get the following error message:
'7z' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Does anyone know how I can add the 7z functionality into my Xampp installation? It's really strange that I can use command prompt fine, but not Xampps shell version of command prompt which is closely identical.

Comment: Is your environment set? If not set your PATH="your 7z diretory"

Comment: Yeah it looks like it's all setup properly. I am thinking I have to set some type of environment on the Xampp side though. I just have no idea where to do something like that. I have two command prompts open on my screen right now, one for XAMPP, and one is the default Windows Vista one. The default one works fine and Xampp doesn't :(

Comment: If you have `PHP 5 >= 5.2.0` and `PECL zip >= 1.1.0` then you can use the [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class.